# Are there system calls like posix in assembly level using int number for windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, assembly, kernel

I want to write assembly program using

> windows syscall Interrupt number

, so in order to use system call in assembly level using int of sys call, In windows are there kernel calls like posix library unitsd.h in assembly level. where can i find windows system call list for opening file, mkdir,etc.(interrupt number), like the one in like *_NR_write 4* in linux or unix.

Comment: What you're looking for would be the [DOS API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API), but according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36959534/471129), it isn't supported by modern windows, so you have to call the OS-provided standard libary function instead.

Comment: How does POSIX fit into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The Windows NT kernel API (which is traditionally accessed by using the functions defined in `ntdll.dll`) can be accessed directly by use of the `int 2e` instruction.  However this is not a supported way of using the system, and details of the implementation (including function codes) are likely to change between Windows versions.

The basic approach is:

- place parameters to the function on the stack
- put function code in EAX
- execute `int 2e`
- result is in EAX

There is a table of function codes here: http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi/

Comment: Do you have a reference for amd64 ?